Why can't Moore graphs contain cycles of length 3 or 4?
We say a $k$-regular graph $G$ is a Moore graph if $G$ has diameter $2$ and $1+k^2$ vertices. Apparently the following is an equivalent definition if $k>1$:

A Moore graph is a $k$-regular graph such that for any distinct vertices $x$ and $y$, there is exactly one path of length at most $2$ between $x$ and $y$.

Why are these definitions equivalent? I can prove that the second definition implies the first (see below), but it's not clear to me why the first implies the second, i.e. why a Moore graph (using the first definition) does not contain a triangle or a 4-cycle.

Proof that the second definition implies the first:
The diameter can't be $1$ (else we get a complete graph, which contains triangles) so the diameter is $2$. Starting with any vertex $v$, the neighbors $v_1,\dots, v_k$ are non-adjacent (no triangles). Each $v_i$ is adjacent to $k-1$ more distinct vertices $v_{i,1}, \dots, v_{i, k-1}$, none of which are mutually adjacent. Now if $v_{i,p} = v_{j,q}$ for some $1\leq i,j\leq k$, $1\leq p,q\leq k-1$, we get a $4$-cycle $$ v\to v_i \to v_{i,p}=v_{j,q} \to v_j \to v$$ so in total we have at least $1+k+k(k-1)=1+k^2$ vertices.
Also, if $G$ has diameter 2, then $G = \{v\} \cup \Gamma(v)\cup \Gamma(\Gamma(v)) $ so $|G| \leq 1 + k + k(k-1)=k^2+1$.

Usually your "alternate definition" is the definition of a Moore graph of diameter 2. This is an example of a result in extremal combinatorics, where by restricting the diameter, degree, and girth (shortest cycle length) of a graph, we can bound the number of vertices; or vice-versa, by restricing the diameter, degree, and number of vertices, we can bound the girth.
For the implication you are looking for, just count the paths of length 2. Each vertex is the middle of ${k \choose 2}$ such paths, giving $$(k^2 +1){k \choose 2} = (1/2)(k^{2}+1)(k)(k-1).$$
Then count the number of paths of length 1 (edges). The total gives you ${k^2 +1 \choose 2}$, which is the total number of pairs of vertices. Since the diameter of the graph is 2, every pair of vertices is connected by at least one path of length 1 or 2, this count shows that they are connected by a unique such path.
